# sed html parsing

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, html

I have to parse HTML to change text between two brackets that are not HTML code back to `&lt;` or `&gt;`.

Here an example of my HTML code that I have to replace:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<div class="pre_headline">some text</div> <p>…. More text . </p><p></p><h2> More text </h2><p> More text < text between angle brackets > … more text
… </content:encoded>
```

desired output:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<div class="pre_headline">some text</div> <p>…. More text . </p><p></p><h2> More text </h2><p> More text &lt; text between angle brackets &gt; … more text
… </content:encoded>
```

All the text is in one line.
All the replacement I'm doing now  is with sed or awk.
But I couldn't figure out a way to replace the brackets in text without changing all the html tags.

I thought to define that all html brackets are not followed by a space. the inline text brackets are usually followed by a space. This could be a way to choose which brackets i have to replace. Maybe there is a better rule, since this method would not replace text in brackets without space :(

The following sed command would replace all brackets.

```
sed -e 's/>/\&gt;/g' | 
sed -e 's/</\&lt;/g' |
```

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint, ...).

Comment: This will be impossible to do unless you can find a way to define which `<` are good and which ones aren't. If they don't always have spaces around them, I don't see how anyone (including a human) can know which `< >` to change and which to leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with **sed** but rather difficult then any XML parsers.

```
sed '
:2
#puts open and close tag in one pattern
/\s*<\([^>]*>\).*<\/\1\s*$/!{
    N
    b2
}
#mark pairable tags by `#` symbol
:1
s/\(.*<\)\(\([^#> ]*\).*<\)\/\3/\1#\2#\/\3/
#other variant
#s/\(.*<\)\(\([^><]*\)[^>]*>.*<\/\3\)>/\1#\2#>/
t1
#change non-marked text
s/<\([^#]*\)>/\&lt;\1\&gt;/g
#remove marks
s/#//g
' file.html
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the OP's example. It also changes the `<` of the `<p>` which is right after the `</h2>` and it doesn't change the `<` of `< text between`. I don't understand how you define "pairable" tags, the target tags are also paired. Also, if I understand correctly, this will fail for unpaired tags, such as `<br>`, which should be left alone. That is impressive sed-fu though.

Comment: @terdon The OP example is broken because its miss `</p>` close to end and `</!> after `<![CDATA`… In the case XML parsers get error too. *Paired tag* I mean started with same name in `<>` with `/` e.g. `<p></p>`, `<div ...></div>`, `<content:encoded></content:encoded>`. The unpaired tags should be operated separatelly by `s/<\(br\)>/<#\1/g`

Comment: Yeah, but you can't expect HTML to always have `</p>` tags. This is probably the best possible answer without a dedicated parser but it still fails :(